# Create Table dynamically from 2 mySQL table and allow updates

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net

What I have are two mysql tables as such for example:

```
Table 1:

----------------
|  ID |  Time  |
****************
| 1  | 3:00pm  | 
----------------    
| 2  | 4:00pm  | 
----------------
| 3  | 5:00pm  | 
----------------
| 4  | 6:00pm  |
 ---------------
| 5   7:00pm   |    
================ 

Table 2:
----------------
|  ID  |  Type |
****************
|  1   |   A   |
----------------    
|  2   |   B   | 
----------------
|  3   |   C   | 
----------------
|  4   |   D   |
----------------
|  5   |   E   |    
================
```

What I basically want to achieve is to have a form in ASP.NET which displays the categories `A,B,C,D,E` as columns on top, with the times on the left hand side with text boxes for each cell so that I can place a value and then update another table which maps an allocation. E.G. Category A has 5 at 3pm etc etc.

Is this possible? Also the categories and/or times may vary so the table would have to created based on the values retrieved from a select statement.

*EDIT*

Quick hash up in Excel to show what I mean, so basically it creates the rows and columns based on what it retrieves from mySQL. Then I can type in the text box for each cell and click an update button which stores the values in a separate table I have for allocations.

[image: img1]

Comment: can you please put picture how you want?

Comment: I am not sure if this will help but I would recommend to create a store procedure that joins the two table based on ur id and returns the type and time. You can then access this based on an SQL connection and store it in an array list. Using that arraylist you can update the gridView and edit it accordingly

Comment: it looks like ill have to play about with this, i'll post back once i get a chance to look at it again in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to have an ID which is the primary key and then another set of ID for each table that will be a foreign key for this to work. So for example, ID > primary key, TypeID(for type table) > foreign key relates to time, and TimeID(for time table) > foreign key relates to type. That's really the only way i see you combining the tables for the update. Now for putting this in a gridview, might be another issue. For that i'd refer you to this:[How to merge two tables](http://forums.asp.net/t/1668955.aspx/1)